# NodeJS async function calls and SQLite3

Tags: node.js, sqlite

One of the thing keeping me from using things like NodeJS is ascynchonious function call, I cannot seem to get a grasp on it. At the moment I'm forcing myself to rewrite a Perl/Dancer2 app to NodeJS. Seems other maintainers cannot make head or tails of Perl. Go figure :S

Anyway, I do run into a async issue once again. And made myself a test cast. It looked like I finally got the beast going. But for reasons I do not understand its SQLite which is action up now.

I made myself the following little script:

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

const db = new sqlite3.Database('./db/presence.sqlite');

function getLocaties(){
    return new Promise((resolve)=>{
        var locaties = [];
        var qry = "Select naam From locaties";
        db.all(qry,[],(err,row)=>{
            if(err){throw err;}
            locaties.push(row);
        });
        resolve(locaties);
    });
}

async function asyncCall(){
    const result = await getLocaties();
    console.log(result);
    console.log('blaat');
}
console.log('asyncCall returns: ');
asyncCall()
.then(() =>{
    console.log('doing it flat: ');
    var qry = "Select naam From locaties";
    db.all(qry,[],(err,row)=>{
        if(err){throw err;}
        console.log(row);
    });
});
```

Which renders the following output:

```
asyncCall returns: 
[]
blaat
doing it flat: 
[
  { naam: 'presence.ict.writer' },
  { naam: 'presence.test.reader' },
  { naam: 'presence.test.writer' },
  { naam: 'presence.test2.writer' }
]
```

I fail to understand why the JQLite query returns an empty result in getLocaties()

Comment: When I place a console.log in the getLocaties id does in fact give me some output, out of sync. As if the db.all() is not waited upon. Giving me yet again an async hell.

Comment: db.all is also async.

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

Turned out that using `db.all()` and moving the `resolve()` did the trick. I did not even need the intermediate locaties array anymore.

```
function getLocaties(){
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    var qry = "Select naam From locaties";
    db.all(qry, [], (err, rows) => {
      //console.log(row);
      resolve(rows);
    });
  });
}
```

gave me the output:

```
asyncCall returns: 
[
  { naam: 'presence.ict.writer' },
  { naam: 'presence.test.reader' },
  { naam: 'presence.test.writer' },
  { naam: 'presence.test2.writer' }
]
```

blaat
doing it flat:

```
[
  { naam: 'presence.ict.writer' },
  { naam: 'presence.test.reader' },
  { naam: 'presence.test.writer' },
  { naam: 'presence.test2.writer' }
]
```

just as I was expecting.